# How to import downloaded android source from internet(git) into eclipse

Tags: android

I downloaded android source code from git ,But I want to include this total source code into eclipse.how is it possible can any one explain?

Thanks for that ,But while porting android source into device ,i have to debug camera service through eclipse.for this debug i want to export total android source to eclipse(like frameworks ,packages,..... all these things)

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse try

File>New>Android Project>

this will open a window. On that window under the contents tab select "Create project from exsting source. "

Now in the location field add the location of your project. If you want you can give the name of the project(look at the top of this window). The Project name and sdk will be automatically selected, if you want you can change it

Comment: Thanks for that ,But while porting android source into device ,i have to debug camera service through  eclipse.for this debug i want to export total android source to eclipse(like frameworks ,packages,..... all these things)

Comment: @saipradeep -- you want to add the jar files?

Comment: @saipradeep -- this post is closed, so i can't post an answer any more. To get an answer, post this as a separate question. If you find the above answer as an useful one then please accept the answer and vote up